# Jquery: is there a way to attach click event before/after before the regular click event of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, anchor

What I'm trying to accomplish is:
Clicking on anchor tag that has href like this "href = "#sample"" then the browser scrolls down to the tag that has this id and after that I want to execute the click function that i have been attached to the same anchor tag. What happens now is quite the opposite. First the click event executes then the anchor original ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see a direct way there, but you can prevent the browser's default behavior (by returning `false` from your event handler) and manage the scrolling by yourself (take a look  [at this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('...').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // put real handler here
    }, 0);
});
```